# How can i add two parallel paths annotation on High chart?

Tags: jquery, svg, highcharts

```
chart.addAnnotation({
                    x: clickX,
                    y: clickY,
                    allowDragX: true,
                    allowDragY: true,
                    anchorX: 'left',
                    anchorY: 'top',
                    title: title,
                    shape: {
                        type: shape,
                        params: {
                            r: shape == 'circle' ? 1 : 0,
                            d: shape == 'path' ? ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 1, 1] : null,
                            dd: shape == 'db-path' ? ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 1, 1] : null,
                            x: x,
                            y: y,
                            width: width,
                            height: height,
                            fill: fill,
                            stroke: stroke,
                            strokeWidth: strokeWidth
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You need to add two different annotations.

Comment: Thanks Pawel for reply,                                             Yes it is straight forward but i want to add two parallel lines which behaves like an object of like a rectangle with only two broders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set just proper path for this, like this:

```
d: ['M', 10, 10, 'L', 20, 10, 'M', 10, 20, 'L', 20, 20]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N6GR9/14/

Comment: And one more question is that are we able to fill colour between two lines?

Comment: How would be this different from creating rect?

Comment: But i will not able to make cross lines in rectangle

Comment: I want to fill lines like d: [M 0 0 L 228 32 M 0 20 L 228 52]

Comment: Okay, in SVG you can use `Z` property to make closed path, but you will need to remove second `M`. Then closed path can have fill, see: http://jsfiddle.net/N6GR9/15/